# How do I insert a dotcms form into my generic container?

Tags: forms, variables, dotcms

I have a form created on dotcms with only one variable called email but every time I click add content and add it, it just appears above my container or below.
How do I add it into a div that's already in the container?

Answer (score 0):

The exact field of the content which you are displaying on the front end should be specified within the desired div tag.

E.g. if you have fields called 'title' and 'description' in your content, then your container code can be like-

```
<div class="myclass"> 
   <h1>$!title</h1>
   <p>$!description</p>
</div>
```

Please note that there are many auto generated divs when viewing in the edit/preview mode on which the user doesn't have much control.